# about subsetting a dataframe in R

Tags: r

I would appreciate your suggestions on subsetting a data frame. Let's consider an example data frame `df`:

```
dd <- c(1,2,3)
rows <- c("A1","A2","A3")
columns <- c("B1","B2","B3")
numbers <- c(400, 500, 600)    
df <- dataframe(dd, rows, columns, numbers)
```

and a vector : `test_rows <-c("A1","A3")`

How could I subset the data frame `df` function of vector `test_rows` in such a way that only the row of data frame `df` (`df$rows`) that match the elements of `test_rows` ("A1" and "A3") are listed?

Comment: You can use the function "subset"

Comment: http://www.ats.ucla.edu/stat/r/faq/subset_R.htm. First result for Google query "R subset data frame". I may be not giving you adequate benefit-of-the-doubt, but your question "does not show any research effort."

Answer (score 5):

Here is your answer:

```
df[df$rows %in% test_rows,]
```

btw, `df` is a name of a built in function in R so it is better not to use it as a name for variables.

Comment: Where is `df`a reserved word? I saw here: https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/Reserved.html but there's not `df`.

Comment: df is a function. This is what happens when I type `df`: `function (x, df1, df2, ncp, log = FALSE)`

Comment: You corrected well because a reserved word is a different thing respect to the name of a function. Try for example to assign a value to `for` of `while` words. Anyway, you can assign values in any case with `"` and take them with `get` function or just assign with backticks ````.

Comment: people tend to use `df` for a lot of examples in stack overflow and it has become a real pet peeve of mine since after helping someone, `df` always shows up when I check `conflicts()`.

Answer (score 2):

Just in case your data set is very large and you want a faster solution here is the `dplyr` code to achieve the same result:

```
df %>% filter(rows %in% test_rows)
```